# Writing and Retrieving Cookies in JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

Alright so I have this assignment for my class and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I need to insert an `initPage()` function to the sbutton that calls `saveMailingInfo()` and it has to run when the page loads. I also need to write a `saveMailingInfo()` function that creates an 3 year expiration date and loops through each element of the mailing form. I was certain I did it right but I don't get the alert when I test it. Any ideas?

```js
/* this function attachs the event handler under both event models */
function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
 if (object.attachEvent)
  object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
 else if (object.addEventListener)
  object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}



function writeCookie(cName, cValue, expDate, cPath, cDomain, cSecure) {
  if (cName && cValue != "") {
     var cString = cName + "=" + escape(cValue);
     if (expDate) 
        cString += ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();

     if (cPath) cString += ";path=" + cPath;
     if (cDomain) cString += ";domain=" + cDomain;
     if (cSecure) cString += ";secure";


     document.cookie = cString;
  }


function saveMailingInfo() {

  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setFullYear(expire.getFullYear() + 3);

  var allFields = document.mailingForm.elements;
  for (var i  = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {

    if (allFields[i].type == "text") {

      writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].value, expire);

    }

    if (allFields[i].nodename == "SELECT") {

      writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].selectedIndex, expire);

    }

    if (allFields[i].type == "radio") || allFields[i].type == "checkbox") {

  writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].checked, expire);

}

  }


}

  alert("Cookie has been written!");
}

addEvent(window, "load", initpage, false);

  function initPage(){

    document.getElementById("sbutton").onclick = saveMailingInfo;
    console.log(document.cookie);

  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- DW6 -->
<head>
<!-- 
 


-->
<title>Cakes by Emily</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cakeForm.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
<div class="head" id="header">
  <p><img src="cake.jpg" alt="cake picture" /><img src="logo.gif" alt="Cakes by Emily" width="400" height="125" /></p>
  <div class="links" id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Cakes</a>
    <a href="#">Pastries</a>
    <a href="#">Pies</a>
    <a href="#">Mailing List</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">
<p>Enter your info to be added to our email list with reminders about getting that birthday 
cake you want! Remember at Cakes by Emily, we aim to make every birthday the best!</p>
<form name="mailingForm" >
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
  First:

   </td>
   <td> <input type="text" name="firstName"  id="firstName"><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Last: 
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  E-Mail: 

   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" ><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy): 

   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday" ><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Favorite Cake: 

   </td>
   <td>
    <select id="favoriteCake">
     <option value="ButterCream">Butter Cream</option>
     <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
     <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
     <option value="RedVelvet">Red Velvet</option>
   </select><BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  Frequency of Emails: 

   </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency1" >Email me monthly<BR>
       <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency2" >Email me quarterly<BR>
       <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency3" >Email me near my birthday<BR>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="sbutton" name="sbutton"  value="Join our mailing List" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset the form" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Let me Google that for you](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cookies%20javascript)

Comment: I would also recommend installing a cookie viewer plugin on your browser so you can see what is being set. In Firefox, I know there is one built in you can access by going to Menu->Developer->Developer Toolbar, then typing `cookie list` and pressing Enter.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that and none of the cookies are saving. Not really sure what I did wrong.